# In mongodb - Can the document content contain curly braces?

Tags: mongodb, bson

While inserting a document in mongodb, one of the variables in the object that I am trying to insert contains curly braces '{abc123}' as a part of value.

This is causing the inserts to fail. Any way around it?

Comment: Escape the braces ??

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use both double and single quotes: `"'abc123'"`. Double quotes will mark the JavaScript string and single quotes will be handled as literal values, as if it was escaped with backslash.